# How do I pass radio button values to <Return> event?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Using Python 3 and tkinter, I'm making a GUI tool to search a large corpus -- bigger than, say, the Bible.
I got the interface designed. After reading docs, looking at tutorials and such, I can't figure out how to pass the values of the radio buttons that will control how the search is performed.

The radio buttons are not set to trigger on change, since there are 4 sets of them and I need to do different kinds of searches or outputs depending which buttons are selected. So I have the event set to trigger on the enter key from an Entry box:

`grc_inp.bind('<Return>', doReturn)`

I've tried several different ways to pass the radio button values and nothing works.

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
#
# TryTkinter06.py
# Created 2020-05-04
# Author: Dan Beatty
#
"""
GUI in Python. Trying to start processing input.
"""

import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *

def doSearch(m, c, a, o, needle):
    # STUB
    print('Match type:', m)
    print('Case sensitivity:', c)
    print('Accent sensitivity:', a)
    print('Output desired:', o)
    print('Search term:', needle)

def doReturn(event):
    mst = mstate.get()
    cst = cstate.get()
    ast = astate.get()
    ost = ostate.get()
    search_for = grc_inp.get()
    # doSearch(mst, cst, ast, ost, search_for)

def main():
    rootWin = tkinter.Tk()

    # make panes
    pWin = tkinter.PanedWindow()
    pWin.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    panes = tkinter.PanedWindow(rootWin, orient=VERTICAL)
    pWin.add(panes)
    topPane = tkinter.Label(panes)
    panes.add(topPane)
    botPane = tkinter.Label(panes, text='bottom pane')
    panes.add(botPane)

    # make radiobutton sets
    # match state set
    mstate = tkinter.StringVar()
    ms_label = tkinter.Label(topPane, text='Match Type:')
    ms_part = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='partial word', variable=mstate, value='partial')
    ms_whole = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='whole word', variable=mstate, value='whole')
    ms_phrase = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='phrase', variable=mstate, value='phrase')
    # case state set
    cstate = tkinter.StringVar()
    cs_label = tkinter.Label(topPane, text='Case Matching:', bg='#dddddd')
    cs_insen = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='insensitive', variable=cstate, value='insensitive', bg='#dddddd')
    cs_sens = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='sensitive', variable=cstate, value='sensitive', bg='#dddddd')
    # accent state set
    astate = tkinter.StringVar()
    as_label = tkinter.Label(topPane, text='Accent Matching:')
    as_insen = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='insensitive', variable=astate, value='insensitive')
    as_sens = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='sensitive', variable=astate, value='sensitive')
    # output state set
    ostate = tkinter.StringVar()
    os_label = tkinter.Label(topPane, text='Output Type:', bg='#dddddd')
    os_hits = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='hit count', variable=ostate, value='hits', bg='#dddddd')
    os_refs = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='list references', variable=ostate, value='refs', bg='#dddddd')
    os_context = tkinter.Radiobutton(topPane, text='show context', variable=ostate, value='context', bg='#dddddd')

    # input box for grc search term
    grc_label = tkinter.Label(topPane, text='Search for:')
    grc_inp = tkinter.Entry(topPane, width=50)

    ms_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    ms_part.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    ms_whole.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    ms_phrase.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    cs_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    cs_insen.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    cs_sens.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    as_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    as_insen.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    as_sens.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    os_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    os_hits.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    os_refs.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    os_context.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    grc_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5)
    grc_inp.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=W, ipadx=10, ipady=5, pady=5)

    grc_inp.bind('<Return>', doReturn)

    rootWin.title('Search Corpus')
    rootWin.geometry('1500x750')
    rootWin.mainloop() # creates the window




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Screenshot of GUI:
[image: GUI Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide us some code? That way, we know how to give your answer. Please read [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimum-reproducible-example).

Comment: Edited to add code, now my picture is broken.

Comment: fixed the screenshot

Comment: Put the functions inside a class and use instance variables to store the references of widgets.  Then you can directly use the instance variables in any functions of the class.

Comment: So you are suggesting I go through a whole OOP learning curve to be able to do this?

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what @acw1668 is suggesting. OOP is the only way of doing this, unless you want to write a billion lines of code seeing which one the user selected.

Comment: @acw1668, ok, thanks. Since this was just a tool to make my use of the corpus easier, I guess I just need to abandon the idea. I'm not about to go into a full fledged programming course at this time and distract myself from my real purpose here.

Comment: If you really don't want to go OOP, then you can declare `mstate`, `cstate`, `astate`, `ostate` and `grc_inp` as global variables at the beginning of `main()`: `global mstate, cstate, astate, ostate, grc_inp`.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks, I'll try that. It's not that I don't want to go OOP. I've tinkered with learning it in the past and never get past useless tutorial examples to practical design in my own programs. This whole tkinter thing has already been too much distraction from my real work already, though.